# Getting R, G, or B in Buffered image

Tags: java

I have a piece of a method that I am working on. The goal of this is to loop over every pixel in an image, get the values of the pixels around it and create a gradient that I can then compare to a threshold to decide if there is an edge present. I get an error of "Cannot invoke getBlue() on the primitive type int" and I cannot figure out why.

```
int grad = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<img.getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<img.getHeight(); j++) {

            grad += abs(img.getRGB(i+1,j).getBlue()-img.getRGB(i-1,j).getBlue() + abs(img.getRGB(i,j+1).getBlue()-img.getRGB(i,j-1).getBlue());
            grad += abs(img.getRGB(i+1,j).getGreen()-img.getRGB(i-1,j).getGreen()) + abs(img.getRGB(i,j+1).getGreen()-img.getRGB(i,j-1)getGreen());
            grad += abs(img.getRGB(i+1,j).getRed()-img.getRGB(i-1,j).getRed()) + abs(img.getRGB(i,j+1).getRed()-img.getRGB(i,j-1).getRed());
```

Answer (score 3):

getRed(), getGreen(), and getBlue() are all methods of the class Color. You have to encapsulate the RGB value in a Color object prior to calling the methods. For example:

```
new Color(img.getRGB(i + 1, j)).getBlue();
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your entries is getblue() and others are getBlue(). The case will matter.

Also you are taking i and j from 0 to width or height. At edges at least one of i-1, i+1, j-1 and j+1 will be out of range. At corners, 2 will be out of range.

Answer (score 0):

The RGB value returned by [`BufferedImage#getRGB`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB(int,%20int)) is a packed `int`, it is not a `Color` object.  A cursory glance at the JavaDocs or your IDE auto sense properties would have told you this.

You can unpack the `int` value using binary shifting, but I prefer to use [`Color(int, boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int,%20boolean)), which will unpack the pack RGB value into a `Color` object.

This method also allows you to specify if the `alpha` channel should be included or not